# How can I use lua to start a server

Tags: lua

I have a test server, it is a loop. I want to start this server use `lua`.
The server is like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("wait %d s\n", 5 - i);
    }
}
```

and I have have compiled it

`g++ server.cpp -o server`

And I write a `start.lua` file like this

```
local executable = "./server"
local exitcode = os.execute(executable)
if exitcode == 0 then
  print("Executable executed successfully.")
else
  print("Failed to execute the executable. Exit code: " .. exitcode)
end

# I do not want to wait the server ends, I should do other things after the server starts
```

then I use `lua start.lua` to start the server, I find only when the `server` ends, there will be `lua` printing `Executable executed successfully.`. How to let `os.execute` return immediately without affecting the server to continue to execute?

Comment: `local executable = "./server &"`

Comment: Explanation of ESkri's answer: The `&` will make your shell run `./server` as a background process, thus the `os.execute` won't block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using lua posix library (https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) that can be installed using luarocks. Also, you can try io.popen, which is non-blocking.

Comment: BTW: `p=io.popen(command)` is non-blocking, but `p:read(n)` is blocking even when you are reading `n=0` bytes

Answer (score 0):

As @ESkri said, I use local executable = "./server &"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).